# How to point cname www to @ in dns management

Tags: amazon-s3

My domain is in godaddy. I have set `CNAME` called `www` as `abcxy.com.s3-website-us-east-2.amazonaws.com`. Now i want the same value to replecated for Type `A` name `@`. But unfortunately it does not accept bucket name , it only accepts ip addres. How to enable it to accept the bucket name?

Comment: I think an A name needs to be an ip address, if you want to use another DNS name I think it needs to be a CNAME

Comment: I want my website e.g `test.com` to point to the same bucket as it does using `www.test.com`

Comment: well it looks like you can do it in google's domain manager... I dont use godaddy anymore... so I can't test there

Comment: maybe you can delete the existing @ record and add it as a CNAME ?

Comment: I have already added `CNAME` called `www`

Comment: You can have lots of CNAMEs but you can only have one record for any subdomain, including @

Comment: But @ only accepts ip address , then how to put bucket name in there?